# MYSQL (WAMP SERVER): Error 1064 when using AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 to create table column?

Tags: mysql, wamp, auto-increment, create-table

I have this code:
`CREATE TABLE Company ( Comp_Code INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT=1000, Comp_Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Comp_Code) );`
but when i run it in MYSQL from WAMPServer it gives an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=1000,
> Comp_Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (Comp_Code)
> )' at line 2

Why is this happening?

Comment: 'I can't seem to find any solution to this particular issue' - review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is column option.

Initial `AUTO_INCREMENT=1000` value is table option.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Company ( 
    Comp_Code INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- specify that the column is AI
    Comp_Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Comp_Code) 
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;                         -- specify initial AI value
```